# Open custom file with keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

On my Mac, I have some applications that were recently made in Java that I will be using quite alot. I want to know, is there a way that I can bind a shortcut on the keyboard to open the file?

For eg. CTRL + CMD + OPTION = Open test.jar located on Desktop.

Is there any 'vanilla'  way or if there is, any 3rd party software that can allow me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) with a macro such as this:

[image]

Comment: Wait never mind sorry, was just a little impatient. Thankyou so much, have been looking for one of these, just perfect!

Comment: And I had to 'enable' not only the 'macro' thing but also the action itself.